# Delete only the first occurence of the line in a file using Ansible

Tags: linux, shell, sed, ansible

I am using ansible v2.2.1 and I need to remove only the first occurrence of a line in file. So my ansible playbook is as follows.

```
---   
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: read file content
    command: cat occurence.txt
    register: fc
  - debug: var=fc

  - debug: msg="{{ item }}"
    with_items:
     - "{{ fc.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: first occurence in file
    shell: sed -i '0,/{{ item }}/{/{{ item }}/d;}' occurence.txt
    with_items:
     - "{{ fc.stdout_lines }}"
    register: remove
  - debug: var=remove
```

And **occurence.txt** file has following content

```
this is apple
this is apple
this is banana
this is apple
this is orange
```

How can I delete only the first occurrence of line "this is apple" and leave rest of the lines?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is going to happen on subsequent playbook runs?

Comment: use `uniq` or `sort -u` not `sed`.

Comment: @stevesliva Not sure that your comment fits the question. OP asks for a specific line to be handled. Sort and uniq will remove duplicates of all lines.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Maybe take the [tour].

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you want to consume a list, but not neccessarily in FIFO order? Maybe because you have a priority scheme going on? You should add an explanation to the question; that sometimes helps filling in missing information.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've written playbook to remove only first occurrence of a line specified in a file. But playbook is looping through all the lines and removing every line as it is identifying each line as first occurrence.
Now i want to remove only a line eg: first occurrence of "this is apple" and leave rest of the lines in the file.

Comment: @Yunnosch - I'm not sure either.  Seems like the question is trivial if you read it that way.

Comment: @stevesliva I agree, does not seem hard in either interpretation. But OP seems not impressed by either. Hruday, be sure to point out what is not satisfactory. Both of us believe to have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows by using set_fact variable.

```
---

- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - name: read file content
    command: cat occurence.txt
    register: fc
  - debug: var=fc

  - debug: msg="{{ item }}"
    with_items:
     - "{{ fc.stdout_lines }}"

  - set_fact: value="this is apple"
  - debug: var=value

  - name: first occurrence in file
    shell: sed -i '0,/{{ value }}/{/{{ value }}/d;}' occurence.txt
    register: remove
  - debug: var=remove
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm liking Yunnosch's interpretation of the question.  An alternative would be this:

`sed '0,/^this is apple$/{//d}'`

From the beginning of the file to the first occurrence of the apple line, delete only lines matching the previous match.

Comment: Can you explain more? I read "from beginning to apple line, delete all lines that contain an emtpty string", the last part seems to be the same as "delete all lines".

Comment: `//` is sed shorthand for the previous match.   Helps avoid a full repeat of `/END/` in `0,/END/`.   It is also useful as `//!` when using the comma operator on a range.

Comment: Ha! StackOverflow does not only answer your questions, you can also learn things you did not know that you should ask about. Thanks. But may I recommend to explain inside the answer? It might attract well-deserved upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Find line, when found replace by (initially empty) hold space.
For later occurences, swapping to the identical hold space will basically print unchanged line, even if it, strictly speaking, it is the previous identical line.
Delete in case of (only the first) empty line coming from hold space.

`sed  "/^this is apple$/{x;/^$/d}"`

Comment: I was wrong.  *This* problem is actually non-trivial in sed.